# How to create custom urls with dashes in Yii2?

Tags: url, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-url-manager

I am working with advanced project application and trying to add URL rules in Yii2 to handle custom URLs with dashes.

What I want to do is to change the URL from

> http://www.example.com/post/details?url=example-post-title

To

> http://www.example.com/example-post-title

I have below configuration which works fine when the URL parameter does not have dash (exampleposttitle).

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        // ...
        '<url:\w+>' => 'post/details',
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to fix your regexp, since `\w+` does not allow dashes:

```
'<url:[\w-]+>' => 'post/details',
```